# Nunjucks access window screen size

Tags: templating, nunjucks

Is there a way to get window size parameters with Nunjucks?
Currently I am trying:

```
{% if window.screen.width < 800 %}
    {% include 'partials/sort.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

As I understand, Nunjucks templating does not have access to front-end parameters, but is there any way to go around this? (for the record, i am using nodejs for server-side code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a window size in cookies and pass them values into a render `res.render(templ, {cookies})`: if size-cookies don't exists on a page request then return a "special" page where you store window size to cookies and redirect to the requested page.

Here example of this way (`app.js` requires installed `express` and `nunjucks` modules):

```
// app.js
var express = require ('express');
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var app = express();
var env = nunjucks.configure('.', {autoescape: true, express: app});

function parseCookies(cookies) {
    return cookies && cookies.split(';').reduce(function(res, cookie) {
        var pair = cookie.split('=');
        res[pair.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(pair.join('='));
        return res;
    }, {}) || {};
}

app.get('/set-cookie', function(req, res) {
    res.render('setter.html');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    let cookies = parseCookies(req.headers.cookie) || {};
    if (!cookies.width || !cookies.height)
        return res.redirect('/set-cookie?' + req.url);

    res.render('index.html', {width: cookies.width, height: cookies.height});   
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000...');
});

// index.html
<html>
<body>
{{width}} x {{height}}
</body>
</html>

// setter.html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // store window size to cookies and redirect to origin page 
    function setWindowSize () {
        document.cookie = 'width=' + window.innerWidth;
        document.cookie = 'height=' + window.innerHeight;
        location = location.search.substring(1); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "setWindowSize()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any example how to actually store window size data into a cookie? ```res.cookie('window size', {
  wd: window.innerWidth
 });``` Never worked with cookies before

Comment: Maybe it's too late. I added a example app :)

Comment: So since I've got this working, are there any restrictions or special agreements I need to inform my website's visitors about these cookies?

Comment: In addition, this overall solution with nunjucks and cookies does not work on window resize event. Because server code observes width/height only one time when it loads.

Comment: I don't know about special agreements, maybe a standard cookies note. You can check cookie-values and window-size on page load and redirect/reload page if they is not equals.